# Problem with Eclipse: "An Error has occurred. See the log file ......"

Tags: 13.04, eclipse

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and when I want run Vega program by `./Vega` 
I get this message

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/engalaabt/.eclipse/1150212041/configuration/1371636662714.log.
```

so what is the problem and how i can fix it ?

Comment: What's in the log file? If it's too big upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure eclipse-pde eclipse-jdt
```

Click [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133528)! for more details.

Comment: This is only a part of the (reported as working) solution. So please edit your answer to mention all necessary steps.

Comment: a part .. that is why I put a link. 
and I put the code because it worked for me with no thing else!.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
sudo chown MYUSERNAME. ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/*
sudo chmod 755 ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/*
```

[source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1000272)